# Lint-staged aborts check with the first failing file; "Error: Unknown argument"

Tags: lint-staged

With `"lint-staged": "^13.0.3"` and the following `.lintstagedrc` config:

```
{
  "src/**/*.{ts,html}": [
    "ng lint"
  ],
  "src/**/*.scss": [
    "npx stylelint **/*.scss"
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to run `npx lint-staged -q` on the following files (all of them have lint problems that would come up with the individual lint command):

[image]

Running `ng lint` and `npx stylelint **/*.scss` directly will bring up the problems (detailed) and would not fail on the first file:

`ng lint`

[image]

`npx stylelint **/*.scss`

[image]

I'd like `lint-staged`'s output to show all of the problems from the individual lint commands. What's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after further investigation;

1. The partial output problems seem to be introduced to `lint-staged` on versions >= 12.2.0, see on [github](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/1189). I've downgraded to `"lint-staged": "12.1.7"` and the problem seems to be gone.
2. Regarding the `Unknown argument` thing, it resolves by calling `eslint` instead of `ng lint` on the configuration file.